# A Turing machine which computes $x^y$

Tags: automata, turing-machines

Question:

> Design a Turing machine which takes two integers $x$ and $y$ and outputs $x^y$.

Note 1: The representation of $x$ and $y$ is not mentioned in the question but you can use either the binary or the unary one.

Note 2: I know how to design a Turing machine for $x\cdot y$ and I think it can be helpful in designing the machine which the question wants.  But I don't know how. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @orlp gives a good answer.  I would add that unary notation would make actually coding this the easiest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you know how to design a Turing machine for $x\cdot y$.

Do you know how to check if a number is $0$, and go to a halting state?

Can you subtract $1$ from a number?

Start off the input with `x#y`, where `#` is some separator symbol. Append $1$, giving `x#y#1`. Now encode the following:

1. If the second number is $0$, halt (with potential cleanup for output first).
2. Multiply the third number by the first number.
3. Subtract $1$ from the second number.
4. Goto 1.

Comment: Why multiply the third number by the first number? I don't get the idea... How is it related to $x$ to the power of $y$? Isn't it $x \times 1$ ?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade The first number is $x$, the third number is $1$. We multiply the third by the first number, $y$ times, to get $1 \cdot x \cdot x \cdots x$ where $x$ is repeated $y$ times. In other words $x^y$.